# What mocking framework do you suggest for C++ on a linux platform?

Tags: linux, c++, unit-tests

The company I work for recently added Linux to our work environment and we need a good unit testing framework for c++. 
We tried Gmock from google but it's not so user-friendly.
I have done a little research and found Parasoft's C++ test, and Typemock's Isolator++. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. Can you please give more details what your requirements are? What are the "must have" requirements?

Comment: The most important thing for us is that the mocking framework will be user-friendly

Comment: The user-friendly part really depends on your environment. Do you use CMake, Jenkins, etc.? What is your current unit testing framework? What exactly was the problem with Gmock? At the moment I understand your question like ["which C++ unit testing frameworks are the most popular right now and why"](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4e9afx/most_popular_c_unit_testing_frameworks/), because it looks like your not only searching for a mocking environment but also for a C++ testing framework.

Comment: We use Jenkins and we tried Google Test with Gmock.
Google Test was great as a unit testing framework, but we had some problems with Gmock since it was not user-friendly.
I learned that Isolator++ is integrated with Google Test. Have you tried it by any chance? Do you know if C++ Test is integrated with Google Test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a mocking framework I use [`hippomocks`](https://github.com/dascandy/hippomocks). It can be combined with any unit testing framework.

The advantage is that it's a header only framework that does the mocking part during runtime (no pre-build steps required). The down-side is it works only in Intel based architectures.

What I really like is that it also allows to mock static functions.

**References**

- [Hippo Mocks Tutorial 3.0](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/hippomocks/Tutorial_3_0)
- [Hippo Mocks Wiki](http://hippomocks.com/Main_Page)