# Current mocking frameworks for Boost::test

Tags: open-source, library, mocks

First of all, I'm well aware , that exactly the same question have been asked previously:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759560/boosttest-and-mocking-framework
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604549/mocking-with-boosttest
- [What mocking framework do you suggest for C++ on a linux platform?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50261/what-mocking-framework-do-you-suggest-for-c-on-a-linux-platform)
- [Mocking frameworks for C/C++ on Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50293/mocking-frameworks-for-c-c-on-linux)

The problem is, some of them are several years old and many answers are outdated by now.

At first, I wanted to use Turtle, but, according to [the news](https://sourceforge.net/p/turtle/news/) it seems, that it's not being developed anymore. FakeIt, on the other hand is being actively developed, but it isn't thread-safe and it doesn't support Intel compilers, which is a major drawback for me. Also, I don't want to use GoogleMock, as it needs GoogleTest and I don't want to migrate from Boost::test.

Lastly, we don't want to use Isolator++, as it's a paid software and we'd like to stay in the open-source zone.

So, are there any other, actively developed, mocking frameworks, which are compatible with Boost::test?